# codeigniter - connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm having problem connecting database in Codeigniter.

I already configured the `config/database.php` correctly.

In `GetPrefecture.php` controller, I have this code;

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH."controllers/batch/GetIndustry.php");

class GetPrefecture extends BaseController
{

private $prefectures;
private $tableName;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model("PrefectureModel", "prefModel");
}

public function init() 
{
    $result = $this->db->conn_id;
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

I want to test if DB is connected to CI, so I run;

```
php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init
```

But it throws an error;

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: controllers/batch/GetPrefecture.php
Line Number: 12
```

What could I possibly miss?

Comment: Host, DB name, DB user, DB password ??? Only you can know ...

Comment: Just to let you know you have named your class wrong only the first letter should be upper case for class and filename http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming